# Starting an application from networkshare wont start, from subfolder it will

Tags: c#, windows, networking, share

I've created a folder in the root of the D-drive of my (Windows 2011) server, D:\myapplication, and have put the debug files from my c# project in there (D:\myapplication\app.exe).
Made a network share (drive letter N:) from my desktop to that folder with "Full control" for "Everyone" and I'm local/server/domain administrator.
When I start the executable (N:\app.exe), it will not start the application.

However if I create a subfolder in this share (D:\myapplication\subfolder\app.exe), and move the files in there, the application runs as expected from N:\subfolder\app.exe.

When starting the application from a non-administrator cmd (N:\app.exe) it works too.

What could cause this behaviour?

Also tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee844140(v=ws.10)

Comment: So you have "D:\myapplication\app.exe" , mapped N: there and it won't start, then "D:\myapplication\subfolder\app.exe" and you started from N:\subfolder or did you remap N: to "D:\myapplication\subfolder" ?

Comment: What is the error when you run it from a command prompt?

Comment: Added the requested info in my Original post
@Fildor: I did not remap, but inserted the subfolder name to the path
@ smoore4: than it works like expected

Comment: Drive letter mappings are per-user.  So an admin or elevated user will not see the mappings created by a non-elevated user.  And the other way around.

Comment: @Hans, 
The user who made and uses the local mapping is local/server and domain admin, so I do not understand your suggestion, maybe you can elaborate on it

Comment: A user is never both on modern Windows versions.  You typically elevate through the UAC prompt to get admin privileges.  But the drive mappings will not be the same.

Comment: I'm not prompted either in the non working situation, or in both working situations